# How to create an html object and append sibling to that from an array using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

```
var html=$("<span>Number</span>"); 

$.each([1,2,3,4,5],function(index,item){
    html.add($("<span>"+item+"</span>"));
});
```

From the above sample code, "html" - is span object. I want to append all array elements as sibling for this "html" object.

**Expectation result:**

[1,2,3,4,5] -> total 5 elements bind as span objects with sibling of "html" object.

**Actual result :**

if i try to use add or append its binding as a child element of "html" object.

Please guide me.. Thanks on advance!

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you want to do. Are you looking for .after -> http://api.jquery.com/after/ ?

Comment: Try creating a div to hold all the spans.

Comment: I don't see any HTML here .. Do you just need an array with all the spans in it ?

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
html = html.add($("<span>"+item+"</span>"));
```

The [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/add/) says that it **returns** a new collection, not changing the existing one.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need a jQuery object to do this, you can just build a HTML string and then use it however you like

See the example below.

```js
var html = "<span>Number</span>";

$.each([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], function(index, item) {
  html += "<span>" + item + "</span>";
});

$("#insert").append(html);
```

```css
span {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="insert"></div>
```

Comment: i am not able to make as string . because, I am doing lots of stuff with individual object before appending.

Answer (score 0):

I think jQuery and HTML is confusing you. I can also see a little mistake in the query passed.

All you need to do is define a list, add items and user $("listid").append(item1,item2);

To repeat the word span 6 times, make your object work like an array.